# Xerces - Load schema from string

Tags: java, xsd, schema, xerces

I would like to load an XML schema from string using Xerces, but until now, I can only load it from an URI:

```
final XMLSchemaLoader xsLoader = new XMLSchemaLoader();
final XSModel xsModel = xsLoader.loadURI(file.toURI().toString());
```

Available methods for loading:

```
XSLoader {
    public XSModel load(LSInput is) { }
    public XSModel loadInputList(LSInputList is) { }
    public XSModel loadURI(String uri) { }
    public XSModel loadURIList(StringList uriList) { }
}
```

Is there any option to load XML schema from a string? In my context, the processing is done on client-side, so URI method cannot be used.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not particularly familiar with your problem, but I found this useful code snippet from [ProgramCreek](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS&method=createLSInput) which demonstrates how to obtain an `XSModel` from an `LSInput` object (the first method you listed above).  It is possible to also load an XML schema from an input stream.  I modified the code slightly to arrive at this:

```
private LSInput getLSInput(InputStream is) throws InstantiationException,
    IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    final DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();
    final DOMImplementationLS impl = (DOMImplementationLS)registry.getDOMImplementation("LS");

    LSInput domInput = impl.createLSInput();
    domInput.setByteStream(is);

    return domInput;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
// obtain your file through some means
File file;
LSInput ls = null;

try {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

    // obtain an LSInput object
    LSInput ls = getLSInput(is);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (ls != null) {
    XMLSchemaLoader xsLoader = new XMLSchemaLoader();
    XSModel xsModel = xsLoader.load(ls);

    // now use your XSModel object here ...
}
```

Comment: Based on your answer I managed to build a method for converting a string to XSModel. I posted it for future references, but voted your answer as accepted.

Comment: I appreciate the support.  One of the methods you gave in your question accepted an `LSInput` object, so the trick was finding a way to convert a `File` to `LSInput`.

Comment: Using [LSInput.setStringData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSInput.html#setStringData-java.lang.String-) would save the OP a few lines.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @TimBiegeleisen answer I built a method for converting a string to XSModel.

```
private static XSModel getSchema(String schemaText) throws ClassNotFoundException,
    InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassCastException {
    final InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(schemaText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    final LSInput input = new DOMInputImpl();
    input.setByteStream(stream);

    final XMLSchemaLoader xsLoader = new XMLSchemaLoader();
    return xsLoader.load(input);
}
```